# Unable to use NSFontManager methods in swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, nsfontmanager

In Xcode 6 Beta 6,

I am unable to use any `NSFontManager` methods in Swift.
For example:

```
var fontManager = NSFontManager.sharedFontManager()

fontManager.setAction("changeFont:")
```

I always get the error: *NSFontManager does not have a member named setAction*

This occurs for any method (e.g. `setDelegate`, `setTarget`)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
fontManager.action = Selector("changeFont:")
```

Properties are set using the property syntax in Swift.

In ObjC, properties were declared with (if not using `@property`):

```
- (X) myProp { return ... }
- (void) setMyProp(X value) { ... }
```

In Swift, the property declarations look more like C#:

```
var myProp : X { get { return ... } set { ... } }
```

So you can't call the setter explicitly using the same method name as in ObjC (though I have actually no idea what it will be compiled into...).